# SQL using contains or Like '%%' and IN together

Tags: sql, sql-like, contains, where-in

is there any way to write SQL query where we can perform contains Check  on a column to  a sub query/function

i.e. in this manner

```
select * from where COLUMN contains IN (select * from func)
```

or

```
select * from where '%'+ COLUMN + '%' IN (select * from func)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try This,

```
Select * From  table_name A
Where Exists (Select *  From table_name B 
                 Where B.Column Like '%' + A.Column +'%')
```

Comment: I think this is the closest to what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewed my answer because I seem to misunderstood the question

```
    Select a.*
    from foo a,
    (select * from func) b
    where a.id = b.id or a.id like '%'+convert(varchar,b.id)+'%'
```

This will select records where A result set column id is equal or like %b.id%